# Lighting not working/Final Render is is not lit

Tags: modeling, rendering, light, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I'm trying to make a sword with a heavy amount of refelction (seen below) but when I try to, it doesn't seem to react at all in the final render. It just looks like clay. I put a spot light above it to show how light just doesn't seem to react. I'm trying to make the final render look identical to what is seen in lookdev mode.

[image: What it is meant to look like]
This is what it is meant to look like.

[image: Final Render looks strange]
This is what the final render looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using Look Dev, Look Dev uses an HDRI to light the scene, so you need an HDRI for your final render to get something close to it.

Hope that helps.

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I tried turning on the HDRI in look dev, so I put the background slider all the way up on the tab you have open in the picture above. However it didn't seem to change anything in the final render. Was that what I was meant to do?

Comment: No, you need to open the shader editor Shift F3, then change to World and add a HDRI to your scene, check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VBkj_I-ONk